# Django basic Authentication for remote directory to bring a image

Tags: django, web-services, python-3.x, basic-authentication, remote-server

I have a webpage where we display an image which is hosted in a remote directory which uses Apache Basic Authentication. 
I used this link to make the call http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml and it works.

My problem is that the image is just a small part of the webpage. And it works if I use src=http://uid:Pwd@website.com/images/image01.jpeg. I don't want to pass the username and password without encrpting them. I am not sure how I could implement this. Any help is appreciated. 
BTW all this is in python3.x

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library, maybe you can use it or look at it's source code for a solution:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication
(source code where you can find a hint should be out there - https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/auth.py)

It would be great if you can use SSL over connection if you choose to use basic auth or try to switch to digest auth instead (with SSL preferably).